# Spring Data REST getting exception when trying to save the data

Tags: spring, spring-data

I new to using Spring data rest , so even though this might be a very basic thing I would appreciate it if someone could point what is the mistake that i made or point me in the right direction .

I have an EmployeeRepository which contains the employee entities.

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee,Long>{

@Query("select emp from Employee emp where  emp.employeeId=?1")
Employee findById(String employeeId);
@Query("select emp from Employee emp where emp.officialEmailId = ?1")
Employee findByOfficialEmailId(String officialEmailId);
}
```

Below is a part of the employee entity delcaration .

```
public class Employee extends AbstractAuditingEntity{
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Version
private Long version;


@Size(min = 3, max = 30)
@NotBlank
@Column(unique=true,nullable=false)
private String employeeId;


@Size(min=3,max = 25)
@NotBlank
@Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.NO, store=Store.YES)
private String lastName;

@Size(min=3,max = 25)
@Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.NO, store=Store.YES)
@NotBlank
private String firstName;


@Size(min=3,max = 25)
@Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.NO, store=Store.YES)
private String middleName;
}
```

In my service class I needed to get list of employee entities based on a condition  and set a common property to all those .I tried it and it did not work so I tried something much simpler , I'm trying to set the middle name of all employees to a common value and save it to the db . Here is the code for it

```
@Transactional
public void tempFunction(){

    Iterable<Employee>  empList = employeeRepository.findAll();
    for(Employee e : empList){
        e.setMiddleName("newMiddleName");
        employeeRepository.save(e);

    }

}
```

I'm getting the below exception  **2016-02-20 17:59:08.545 ERROR 533 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException: null**

And the stack trace shows the root cause to be a NullPointerException which I know is not present anywhere near where I'm invoking this code from either in my controller or service . Could someone point if there is any mistake in my code , thanks in advance .

Comment: Do I need to post some additional data or is there anything unclear in what I ask  ??? , could some one please take a look .